# GWT work with com port why not?

Tags: java, gwt

Comm - it's class for work with com port. do actually work with a GWT com port?
In server I run this code:

```
public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        comm term = new comm("COM3", "$KE,WR,6,0\n");

        return "OK";
    }
```

then server don't return OK - with next error it's a new list of errors, I do not understand is why does not work. when you run a console application with the same class all works:

```
        SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.aaa.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at com.aaa.server.comm.<init>(comm.java:23)
    at com.aaa.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.rxtxSerial)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:252)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    ... 46 more
```

rtx WOrks with c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rxtxSerial.dll library, but when i start in server show me error access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.rxtxSerial).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your problem is not clear. I see GWT and COM port in the same line and sense something is wrong. Are you trying to access com port directly from GWT client side code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hell/server/comm
    at com.hell.server.GreetingServiceImpl.GO1(GreetingServiceImpl.java:37)
```

Looks like a packaging/build error to me. Have you included all required jars in your *deployed* solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Your should put the `com/hell/server/comm` containing jar into `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.rxtxSerial)